# I want to create a General Diagram using Highcharts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, highcharts, chartkick

I am using Chartkick and I am interested to use Renderer Chart  [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/renderer)

But there are no docs for it in charkick how do I implement that for dynamic data in Rails

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you want to achieve? Chartkick is library written in Rails. Highcharts is library written in JS. These are two separate libraries, what is your goal?

Comment: i need to use that the chart that i have added the link in rails .. also charkick supports few charts on highcharts by default .. I want to know a way through which the highcharts general diagram can be implemented in rails

Comment: Then I would suggest adding chartkick tag to your question..

Comment: @SureshKumar Did you finally figure out how to do it?

Comment: no not yet I will post the answer here , After I successfully add that in my Rails app